# CakePHP Acl problems

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple authentication system in place on my Cake website and only allow a user to access the index and view of my posts_controller but they cannot add or edit them. I do this with the following code:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow(array('index','view'));
}
```

Now this works fine as they are just redirected to the login page where they can login to access the page but instead of gaining access the get the following error:

```
Warning (512): Could not find AclComponent. Please include Acl in Controller::$components. [CORE/cake/libs/controller/components/auth.php, line 421]
Notice (8): Undefined property: AuthComponent::$Acl [CORE/cake/libs/controller/components/auth.php, line 527]
Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/cake-1.3.8/cake/libs/controller/components/auth.php on line 527
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting errors about ACL as I'm not using ACL anywhere within my app, all I'm doing is simply saying a user must be logged in to access those OTHER actions.

Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

As you fall on line 527 of the AuthComponent, does it mean that somewhere you configured the AuthComponent with something like this:

> $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';

If this is the case, it has the effect to make the AuthComponent use the AclComponent to check if a user is allowed to perform an action.

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication#!/view/1275/authorize